# Compounding two beta distributions

Tags: calculus, probability, integration, probability-distributions, random-variables

If $y|x\sim\text{Beta}(kx,k(1-x))$ and $z|y\sim\text{Beta}(ky,k(1-y))$, then what is the distribution of $z|x$?

The density function of $z|x$ should be given by this integral, but perhaps there is another approach:
$$
\int_0^1 \frac{y^{kx-1}(1-y)^{k(1-x)-1}}{B(kx,k(1-x))}\,\frac{z^{ky-1}(1-z)^{k(1-y)-1}}{B(ky,k(1-y))}\,dy
$$
If no simple solution is possible, could it perhaps be approximated with another Beta distribution?

Comment: If it helps, as $k\to\infty$ we have $(z|x)\to x$, and as $k\to 0^+$ we have $(z|x)\sim\text{Bern}(x)$.